# Primefaces dialog framework - dialog opens only once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to open a dialog on table row click. It works the first time (for each button), but when I close the dialog (manually, with the X in the corner) it wouldn't show next time. After I refresh the page it opens again.

**The page with the table:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="ad" value="#{adsBean.ads}" widgetVar="adsTable" filteredValue="#{adsBean.filteredAds}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{adsBean.selected}" rowKey="#{ad.id}">
        <p:column id="test" headerText="test">
               <h:outputText value="test" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
               <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" action="#{adsBean.viewAd()}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**My dialog**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    dialogcontent
</h:body>
</html>
```

**AdsBean.viewAd**

```
public void viewAd() {
    Map options = [
        modal: true
        ,draggable: false
        ,resizable: false
        ,contentHeight: 470
        ,contentWidth: 620
        ,width: 650
        ,height: 500
    ]
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("fragments/index/viewAdDialog", options, null);
}
```

Any thoughts how to resolve this problem?

Comment: ., but you can try to use [Primefaces Dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml)

Comment: @Khinsu I'm using the same thing you linked. If you mean the basic dialog, I could try that but I want to work with the dialog framework.

Comment: `action="#{adsBean.viewAd()}"` change this code to this `action="#{adsBean.viewAd}"`

Comment: Also add `immediate="true"` in your `commandButton` of `dataTable` and tell me if this helped

Comment: @anas changed action and added immediate but still not working.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why do you want a button in each row when all buttons do exactly the same thing? If you want to show content related to the row you should try to reverse engineer an existing database or table with netbeans, and study the code. By default it uses dialogs in this way. I don't know if eclipse can do the same thing.